# Average inter signout time in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Editing this question: How can I slice this dataframe and create a new one which has company name and timedtamps for only one date?

```
    Google.com 2012-05-01 18:20:27.167000
1   Google.com 2012-05-01 19:16:08.070000
2   Google.com 2012-05-01 19:20:07.880000
3   Google.com 2012-05-01 19:33:02.200000
4   Google.com 2012-05-01 19:35:09.173000
5   Google.com 2012-05-01 20:18:55.610000
6   Google.com 2012-05-01 20:26:27.577000
8  Google.com 2012-05-02 12:51:12.013000
9  Google.com 2012-05-02  12:56:52.013000
10  Google.com 2012-05-02 12:59:55.167000
11  Google.com 2012-05-02 13:04:25.687000
12  Google.com 2012-05-02 13:16:36.263000
```

Some thing like this

```
    Google.com 2012-05-01 18:20:27.167000
1   Google.com 2012-05-01 19:16:08.070000
2   Google.com 2012-05-01 19:20:07.880000
3   Google.com 2012-05-01 19:33:02.200000
4   Google.com 2012-05-01 19:35:09.173000
5   Google.com 2012-05-01 20:18:55.610000
6   Google.com 2012-05-01 20:26:27.577000
```

And then calculate the average inter signout time for this date?

Comment: `differences = [y-x for x,y in zip(my_times,my_times[1:])]` might help you

Comment: @JoranBeasley : I am new to pandas. I didn't understand what the zip function is really doing here? Also, I want to calculate average time differences for each day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this for example :

First I a create your dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO
text = """site date time
1   Google.com 2012-05-01 19:16:08.070000
2   Google.com 2012-05-01 19:20:07.880000
3   Google.com 2012-05-01 19:33:02.200000
4   Google.com 2012-05-01 19:35:09.173000
5   Google.com 2012-05-01 20:18:55.610000
6   Google.com 2012-05-01 20:26:27.577000
8   Google.com 2012-05-02 12:51:12.013000
9   Google.com 2012-05-02 12:56:52.013000
10  Google.com 2012-05-02 12:59:55.167000
11  Google.com 2012-05-02 13:04:25.687000
12  Google.com 2012-05-02 13:16:36.263000
"""
tab = pd.read_table(StringIO(text),index_col=0,sep='\s+')
```

Then split data by date , and compute the mean of time lag for each date.

```
for group,value in tab.groupby('date'):
    print group
    print pd.to_datetime(value.time).diff().mean()

## 2012-05-01
## 0   00:14:03.901400
## dtype: timedelta64[ns]
## 2012-05-02
## 0   00:06:21.062500
## dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```